# react-native-video [android] undefined is not an object (evaluating NativeModuels.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')

Tags: android, react-native

I integrated react native to an existing android app, I am trying to use react-native-video component for displaying video on the application.

- React-native: 0.42.0
- react-native-video: 1.0.0

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

On the MainApplication.java I added this:

```
import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;
....
@Override
    public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new ReactVideoPackage()
        );
}
```

I added this to my settings.gradle (only one in app)

```
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')
```

In my android/app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':react-native-video')
```

And on my react native component:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
....
render() {
return (
  <View>
  <Video source={{uri: 'https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4'}} resizeMode="cover" repeat={true}  />
....
```

The react native component builds correctly but end up showing this warning on a yellow screen and nothing else:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
             undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')
             render@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:46677:73
             http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12555:27
             measureLifeCyclePerf@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12015:14
             _renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12554:45
             _renderValidatedComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12575:78
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12227:55
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12130:40
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             mountChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11615:56
             initializeChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:9929:41
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:10012:28
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12235:48
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12130:40
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12235:48
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12130:40
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12235:48
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12130:40
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             mountChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11615:56
             initializeChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:9929:41
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:10012:28
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12235:48
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:12130:40
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             mountChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11615:56
             initializeChildren@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:9929:41
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:10012:28
             mountComponent@http://localhost:8081/reactnative/wall.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:11170:49
             performInitialMount@http://localhost:8081/reactnati
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed adding the ReactVideoPackage when creating the ReactInstanceManager

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new ReactVideoPackage())//<-- this line fixed
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
```

Comment: Alternatively, running `react-native link react-native-video` can do all necessary changes to link library automatically for you for both Android and iOS.

Comment: What is **ReactVideoPackage())**??

Comment: Is the constructor to instantiate the com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage class that is imported. You can find out more here: [link]( https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

cd ios and pod install
  and again link library

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Animated,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 50}}>

        <Video
          source={{uri: 'YOUR_URL'}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
          ref={ref => {
            this.player = ref;
          }} // Store reference
          onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
          onError={this.videoError} // Callback when video cannot be loaded
          style={styles.backgroundVideo}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  field: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom:10,
  },
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

**Note** react-native link react-native-video

[image]