# Error react-native-video : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTVideoInstance.Constants')

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I would like to use react-native-video in my app. However, what I've done doesn't work :

1. I created a new project using `expo init Project1`
2. Then I installed react-native-video : `npm install --save react-native-video`
3. I used then this : `react-native link react-native-video`

I only have for the moment App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video source={{uri: './small.mp4'}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      // Store reference
       o.nBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
       onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Finally I use `npm start`

I have this error message :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTVideoInstance.Constants')

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js:265:11 in render
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13042:21 in finishClassComponent
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12970:4 in updateClassComponent
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20488:8 in beginWork$$1
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19370:24 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
  [native code]:null in renderRoot
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
  [native code]:null in runRootCallback
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

I followed instructions from react-native-video : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to eject your app from expo and use the bare workflow if you want to use "react-native-video".

Btw, you can use Expo Video instead of react-native-video : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/

Answer (score -2):

You can add jcenter to android/build.gradle like this:

```
 allprojects {
  repositories {
    .... # Keep the rest
    jcenter() {
        content {
            includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

This is worked for me hope it will also do your work