# Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I got this error:

> Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js",
> which threw an exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating '_reactNative.Image.propTypes.resizeMode')

When I write this:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

const ReproductorAudio = () => {
    const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);
    const [selectedAudio, setselectedAudio] = useState(0);
    const currentTrack = audioguias[selectedAudio];
  
    return (
        <View style={stylesTheme.container}>

            <Botones tipo={'atras'} accion={() => {}} posicion={'izquierda'} />

            <Video
                source={{ uri: 'https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4' }}
                paused={pause}
                resizeMode="cover"
                //audioOnly
                //poster={currentTrack.imagen}
            />

        </View>
    );
};

export default ReproductorAudio;
```

It only happens when you put "Video". When I remove it the error does not occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error react-native-video : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTVideoInstance.Constants')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613898/error-react-native-video-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rctvideoinsta)

Comment: I read it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try use `"^6.0.0-alpha.1"` this version